# How to access physical address on Linux in C?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

Just for my study, I'm trying to implement routine to translate from Virtual Address to Physical Address on ARM Linux.

I'm looking at the specification from the material below.
    http://homepages.wmich.edu/~grantner/ece6050/ARM7100vA_3.pdf

I'm implementing the routine in Kernel Module, and I could read TTBR0 for the first step.
But I realized I have to access physical address P using TTBR0 and target virtual address.
I didn't know how to access physical address P, and tried ioremap() to get virtual
address V for that physical address P.

However, when I call ioremap(), it doesn't work and dump backtrace as follows.
Does anyone know how the right way to access physical address?

```
[255075.566078] ------------[ cut here ]------------                            
[255075.570816] WARNING: at arch/arm/mm/ioremap.c:208 __arm_ioremap_pfn_caller+)
[255075.578806] Modules linked in: tv_driver(+) mtk_stp_gps mtk_fm_priv(P) mt66]
[255075.595096] Backtrace:                                                      
[255075.597590] [<c004df38>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [<c057c8c4>] (dump)
[255075.606186]  r7:00000009 r6:000000d0 r5:c005546c r4:00000000                
[255075.611800] [<c057c8ac>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c00817e0>] (warn_slow)
[255075.621378] [<c008178c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x0/0x6c) from [<c008181c>] )
[255075.630390]  r9:ca466000 r8:00000000 r7:4a25b000 r6:00000001 r5:00000004    
[255075.636883] r4:00000290                                                     
[255075.639616] [<c00817f8>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x0/0x2c) from [<c005546c>] (_)
[255075.649740] [<c005537c>] (__arm_ioremap_pfn_caller+0x0/0x104) from [<c00554)
[255075.660186] [<c00554a0>] (__arm_ioremap_caller+0x0/0x64) from [<c0055518>] )
[255075.669115]  r5:00000000 r4:4a25b290                                        
[255075.672730] [<c0055504>] (__arm_ioremap+0x0/0x18) from [<bf144794>] (cl)
[255075.682695] [<bf144720>] (client_init+0x0/0x288 [driver]) from [<c00)
[255075.692774]  r7:00022451 r6:00000000 r5:c07834c0 r4:4018a008                
[255075.698458] [<c0043628>] (do_one_initcall+0x0/0x1a4) from [<c00bf150>] (sys)
[255075.707624] [<c00bf0c4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1a4) from [<c0049b80>] (ret)
[255075.716673]  r7:00000080 r6:40043d6c r5:00022451 r4:4018a008                
[255075.722272] ---[ end trace bffd4c38629759a2 ]---
```

Comment: Why do you ask? Virtual addressing is one of the role of the kernel....

Comment: You are better off not to do this.  In **Linux**, a *virtual* address can map to no physical memory, but to a file.  Linux has layers of *memory management* infrastructure.  There are already *macros* or functions to achieve this.  There are also some **ARM** questions at SO related to this in more of a bare metal context.  However, the topic is **book like**. A physical address can map to more than one virtual address.  I don't think you can go backwards.

Comment: What exactly do you need the physical address for? Typically, this is only needed for memory accesses from devices, in which case you would use some DMA mapping function.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access directly to physical address while the MMU is active. But you have some ways to do it:

-Write an assembly code to disable MMU ( by writing in CP15 register ), so you will be able to write in any physical adress still in assembly.

-Find the virtual offset, with this offset you will be able to find the virtual address V for the physical address P.

-Use ioremap() function ( in your case i don't know why it doesn't work, i need more information :) )

-Use phys_to_virt function describe in arch/arm/include/asm/memory.h, but it's only for direct map ram memory.